# Pulling information from a websites database

Tags: android, json, sqlite

I have an idea for an app. There's a property website, where you enter an area code and a date and it will give you all the properties sold in that area for the specified date. I want my android app to push out information when a property is sold in the specified area. Familiar with native android development. Just wondering what I need to start looking at to retrieve the information from the websites database. I'm familiar with native android development and java.

Comment: AFIK, If you do not own the database, you would not be able to pull the information.

Comment: Does that website provide any kind of api?

Comment: google "screen scraping" , it's obviously frowned upon, but done by many. The BBC sum it up nicely http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/technology-23988890

Answer (score 0):

Hello Read to http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/org/apache/http/package-summary.html to using Json Request to Http Php script or other..

AND Geofence to location in specifed area

regards!

Answer (score 0):

Though you won't be able to just access any old websites's database, if they have an API available, then you can use that data. For example Zillow has a [variety of APIs](http://www.zillow.com/howto/api/APIBenefits.htm) available (though I'm not sure if any one has what your looking for. Try researching property APIs.

ProgrammableWeb.com has a list of [40 Real Estate APIs](http://www.programmableweb.com/news/40-real-estate-apis-zillow-trulia-walk-score/2012/02/15)